# How to sign in without warden callback on rspec (request spec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, warden

I'd like to call `sign_in(user)` on request spec without warden callback.
Does anybody know a workaround?

I want to use something like [bypass_sign_in](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FControllers%2FSignInOut:bypass_sign_in) on request spec.

I tried below.

- 1. I added `Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers` to my spec/rails_helper.rb

```
config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :feature
```

- 2-a. I write request spec like this. 
  It works. but it calls warden callbacks

```
RSpec.describe '/ajax/stores', type: :request do
    context 'login as valid user' do
      it do
        sign_in(user)
      end
    end
end
```

- 2-b. I write request another spec using `login_as`(warden's method)  but it also calls warden callbacks

```
RSpec.describe '/ajax/stores', type: :request do
    context 'login as valid user' do
      it do
        login_as(user, bypass: true)
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: have you tried `login_as(user, run_callbacks: false)`?

Comment: @VasiliyErmolovich Thank you!!! login_as(user, run_callbacks: false) is works. it didn't call my warden callbacks

Comment: awesome! Posted it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `run_callbacks: false` option to Warden's `login_as` helper:

```
login_as(user, run_callbacks: false)
```